# python code returning nan when calling dll inside a for loop

Tags: python, c++, dll

Now I have a very weird behaviour when trying to call a dll (compiled under Visual Studio 2008) in my python code.
I imported the dll using ctypes module as follows:

```html
import ctypes as C

dll = C.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\PyRates\\pyrateslibdll.dll")
```

if I call one of the functions of the dll in just one code line everything works fine, but if I call the same function inside a for loop I get nans even if code it's doing the same stuff. 
For example:

```
ans = {}
for i in [1,2]:
   ans[i] = dll.myfunc(i)
```

returns:

```
ans[i] = nan
```

on some of its calls, whereas if I execute this code:

```
 i = 1
 ans[i] = dll.myfunc(i)
 i = 2
 ans[i] = dll.myfunc(i)
```

I get what I should expect.

Has anyone had the same behaviour?
Thanks for your help
I'm using Python 2.7 in windows 64bit but dll and python are running in 32bit.

Comment: Define `same stuff`. If you are doing it in a `for` loop, then something is definitely changing within each run, and my guess would be that thus the input is different for the function in each run of the loop.

Comment: just edited my question with an example